# didBeginContact, access and change variable of an object

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

Noob in swift(and programming) here. I'm making a simple breakout game in swift spriteKit. It is working, but now i want to add "health" to some of the blocks, but ran into some problems. I have searched google, but found nothing.

first, here is my class:

```
class targets {

var _target: SKShapeNode;
var color: SKColor;
var life: Int;
var positionX: CGFloat = 100;
var positionY: CGFloat = 200;
var isDynamic: Bool = false;
var _name: String = "";


init(life:Int, target:SKShapeNode, name:String, color: SKColor) {
    self.life = life;
    self._target = target
    self._name = name;
    self.positionX = 100;
    self.positionY = 200;
    self.isDynamic = false;
    self.color = color;
}


func spawnTargets() ->SKShapeNode {

    let target = SKShapeNode(rectOfSize: CGSize(width: 20, height: 10));
    target.name=_name;
    target.fillColor=color;
    target.position=CGPoint(x: positionX, y: positionY);
    target.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSize(width: 20, height: 10));
    target.physicsBody?.dynamic=isDynamic;
    target.physicsBody?.friction=0;
    target.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask=physicsCategory.target;
    target.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = physicsCategory.ball;
    target.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask=physicsCategory.ball;
    target.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection=true;
    return target;
}
```

}

I made two instances of 'targets' in the GameScene-class:

```
var target1: targets = targets(life: 1, target: SKShapeNode(rectOfSize: CGSize(width: 20, height: 10)), name: "1", color: SKColor.blackColor());
var target2: targets = targets(life: 2, target: SKShapeNode(rectOfSize: CGSize(width: 20, height: 10)), name: "2", color: SKColor.yellowColor());
```

Function to spawn the blocks:

```
func spawnTarget(){
    var count: Int = 0;
    target1.isDynamic=false;
    target1.positionX=100;
    target1.positionY=200;

    for(var i = 0; i<60; i++){
        if(count==20){ target1.positionY=target1.positionY+11; target1.positionX=100; count=0; }
        target1.positionX=target1.positionX+21;
        let targetOneLives = target1.spawnTargets();
        addChild(targetOneLives);
        count++;
    }
    count=0;

    target2.color=SKColor.yellowColor();
    target2.isDynamic=false;
    target2.positionX=100;

    target2.positionY=target1.positionY+11;
    for(var i = 0; i<60; i++){
        if(count==20){ target2.positionY=target2.positionY+11; target2.positionX=100; count=0; }
        target2.spawnTargets();
        target2.positionX=target2.positionX+21;
        let targetTwoLives = target2.spawnTargets();
        addChild(targetTwoLives);
        count++;
    }
 }
```

and here is my didBeginContact function:

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

    let firstBody = contact.bodyA;
    let secondBody = contact.bodyB;
    let firstNode = firstBody.node as! SKShapeNode;
    let secondNode = secondBody.node as! SKShapeNode;
    let node;         

    if(firstBody.categoryBitMask == physicsCategory.ball && secondBody.categoryBitMask == physicsCategory.target){
        node = secondNode; 
    }
    else if(firstBody.categoryBitMask == physicsCategory.target && secondBody.categoryBitMask == physicsCategory.ball){
        node = firstNode; 
    }
  //This is what i want to do!
  //node.life = node.life - 1
  //if(node.life == 0){ node.removeFromParent(); }
}
```

I want to change the .life property of the 'targets' instance. Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: What exactly is the issue? What happens when you put in your block of code at the end of `didBeginContact`?

Comment: well, it just says something like "SKPhysicsBody does not have a property called life". But thats not the point, the point is i want to access a variable inside of the object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better way to architect this is to subclass `SKShapeNode`. Each target should be an instance of this. That way, in your `didBeginContact`, you can cast the node as your object.

To fix your issue without changing the architecture, when you instantiate targets, you can store them into a local array.

```
var myArray: [targets] = [] // this should be in the scope of the class that all your logic is in
...
var target1: targets = targets(life: 1, target: SKShapeNode(rectOfSize: CGSize(width: 20, height: 10)), name: "1", color: SKColor.blackColor());
var target2: targets = targets(life: 2, target: SKShapeNode(rectOfSize: CGSize(width: 20, height: 10)), name: "2", color: SKColor.yellowColor());

myArray.append(target1)
myArray.append(target2)
```

Then in your `didBeginContact`, you can iterate through the array and check if the node matches the node of your `targets` object.

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

    let firstBody = contact.bodyA;
    let secondBody = contact.bodyB;
    let firstNode = firstBody.node as! SKShapeNode;
    let secondNode = secondBody.node as! SKShapeNode;
    var node: SKShapeNode?
    // reference to target that was hit
    var myTarget: targets?
    // index of target for removal if needed
    var targetIndex: Int?

    if(firstBody.categoryBitMask == physicsCategory.ball && secondBody.categoryBitMask == physicsCategory.target){
        node = secondNode;
    }
    else if(firstBody.categoryBitMask == physicsCategory.target && secondBody.categoryBitMask == physicsCategory.ball){
        node = firstNode;
    }

    // bail out if not a match
    guard node != nil else { return }

    for i in 0..<myArray.count {
        let target = myArray[i]
        if target._target == node {
            // found
            myTarget = target
            targetIndex = i
            break;
        }
    }

    // verify we found the target
    guard myTarget != nil else { return }

    myTarget!.life = myTarget!.life - 1
    if myTarget!.life == 0 {
        // remove node from scene
        myTarget!._target.removeFromParent()
        // remove target from array
        myArray.removeAtIndex(targetIndex!)
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! hmm, seems like it bails out at 'guard myTarget != nil else { return }'

Comment: Set a breakpoint on that line and inspect `myArray` to make sure it contains your two objects. While you're at it, inspect the shape nodes of your objects and compare their memory address to the address of `target` to see if they match.

Comment: The array does contain the objects, and the memory adresses match

Comment: oh, I'm sorry, the memory addresses of 'node' and 'target._target' does not match, if that was what you meant?

Comment: I got it to work now, thanks! I had to declare the 'targets' objects inside of the for loop, and add it in the array.

Comment: @OlaStein Good! Glad you could get it working. Sorry I didn't get back to you earlier